# setTimeout function does not function as expected

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am writing a function which resizes the window using window.ResizeBy 5 seconds after the page loads using setTimeout.

The setTimeout function is supposed to delay the function by five seconds, yet it does nothing.

How do you make setTimeout work in the way that it is supposed to?

```
  setTimeout(
        window.resizeBy(5, 1),
        console.log('resized!')
        , 5000)
```

Thanks for the help

setTimeout should delay the function by five seconds, yet it does nothing.

Comment: you need to pass the first argument as a function. `function() { window.resize... }`

Comment: [MDN's setTimeout documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), have a look at the expected parameters + examples.

Comment: try `setTimeout(function(){ window.resizeBy(5, 1); }, 5000);`

Comment: `window.resizeBy` this is a function `window.resizeBy(5, 1)` this calls the function **immediately** and evaluates to the returnValue. You have to pass a function to `setTimeout`. Like `setTimeout(resizeBy, 5000, 5, 1);` [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Comment: As @VaibhavMandlik said. The reason is: You need to specify a function that setTimeout can call after the 5 seconds have passed. 
In your current code, the resizeBy is called immediately, and the result of that call (which is not a function at all) is passed to setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout takes a function as the first parameter in order to execute correctly. So you need to wrap your code in an anonymous function. Additionally semi-colons are used to end a line of code as opposed to commas.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    window.resizeBy(5, 1);
    console.log('resized!');
}, 5000)
```

Alternatively you can put the code into a separate named function and provide that function as the parameter like so:

```js
function resizeMyWindow() {
    window.resizeBy(5, 1);
    console.log('resized!');
}

setTimeout(resizeMyWindow, 5000);
```

Further information on how the setTimeout global function works can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

To make setTimeout work as intended, you need to pass a `function` as the first argument. Here's the corrected code:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  window.resizeBy(5, 1);
  console.log('resized!');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the surrounding `function`:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  window.resizeBy(5, 1);
  console.log('resized!');
}, 5000);
```